# Why use Node.js if I don't require real-time functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, express, meteor, sails.js

I'm considering using Node.js with a framework such as express, meteor, or sails (a directory with social features such as sharing, messaging and uploading media). I don't have any features planned that explicitly require real-time functionality, so does it make sense to use Node.js anyway instead of Rails?

There's so much buzz around Node.js that I am tempted to use it just so that I don't get left behind.

Answer (score 5):

As DHH wisely [noticed](http://www.infoworld.com/t/javascript/nodejs-keeps-stealing-rails-thunder-232281) regarding Node vs Rails, "everything can be used instead of everything else". That's somewhat true in a sense that, for example, a site in Rails with promptly set up caching can be as fast as one written in Node.js.

Besides, Node is not necessarily about real-time. It's more about being able to handle many light (in terms of processing time needed) requests. If you expect high level of concurrency (I mean, really, expect, not just are dreaming of it) and every request is supposed to be relatively small, then you could consider using Node, just because handling bigger load (up to some point) will require less work with Node.

Bottom line, use what you are good at. Unless you want to try something new. And Node.js is definitely worth trying.

Comment: Agreed on all points.  There's no completely objective reason to use node until you've really hit a limit with something else that deals with node's strengths.  But it's worth putting effort into because it can be the right tool in a lot of little ways for a lot of different things that aren't strictly the highest of highly concurrent applications.  And we all can improve by adding tools to our toolboxes.

Comment: I agree with you, besides people aways think node to webserver. I like to use node to do things like comunicate with usb or serial, xmpp comunication, data serialization, etc. I think node is very powerful tool. And the C integration open a new world of development.

Answer (score 1):

You're question does lack quite a bit of context. 
This question all depends on the context.

If this is contract work or something you want to make money with in the near future and you're not sufficiently skilled with any of the mentioned nodejs frameworks.
Then I would recommend you use whatever you're already good at.

If this is a private project for fun or any other non serious purpose.
Then I would seriously recommend you to try one of mentioned nodejs frameworks.
In my opinion nodejs is currently the cutting edge web technology. As a developer
you should always try to stay on the cutting edge. That way when you learn how nodejs can be used you might find ways to use those things in your professional environment.

I've lately been using meteor a lot and I can highly recommend it, once you get the hang of it you can do truly amazing things that you could never even imagine doing(in a reasonable timespan) in a classic php project.

Also according to some meteor will replace RoR alltogether [blog](http://differential.io/blog/meteor-killin-rails)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from real-time, main plus I've seen is having same team being able to develop JavaScript client code and server side code for UI web applications.  "Code sharing" between client and server seems a pipe dream to me, but same language is really nice.